# filter object doesnt work angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, restangular

I am using Restangularjs, i want to filter my data, but it's not working. I think thats because i get back objects. What should i do ?

```
 app.controller('InventoryListCtrl', function($scope, Inventory, User, Tags, Restangular, inventoryItems) {
        $scope.inventories = inventoryItems;
        $scope.tags = new Tags().query().$object;
        $scope.users = new User().query().$object;
    });
```

My config state

```
app.config(function config( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('inventory',{
url:'/inventory',
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'InventoryCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'inventory/main.tpl.html'
        }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Inventory' }
}
).state('inventory.listview',{
url:'/listview',
    views: {
        "listview": {
            controller: 'InventoryListCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'inventory/inventory.listview.tpl.html'
        }
    },
    data:{ pageTitle: 'Listview' },
    resolve: {
        inventoryItems: function(Inventory){
            return new Inventory().query();
        }
    }
});
});
```

And i cant filter my data

```
<select ng-model="inventory.model" ng-options="inventory.model for inventory in inventories">
     <option value="">Model</option>
</select> 

<tr ng-repeat="inventory in inventories  | filter: search  filter| inventory.model">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run two filters, you have to put both through pipes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="inventory in inventories  | filter: search | filter: inventory.model">
```